# How to get metadata from bluetooth stack using bt_rc.h?

Tags: avrcp

I extracted android bt stack from AOSP and compiled it on arm. 
I implement an application that connect via bluetooth with the phone and provides metadata and controls the volume.

Currently the application can connected via A2DP, using the interface bt_av.h but now i meet the problem that it does not receive the avrcp callbacks related to playStatus,track_change, attributes provided by the interface bt_rc.h.
Studying the AVRCP protocol, it say that at startup the application have to request register_notification_cmd and getcapabilities_cmd but the intrface bt_rc does not support them.

Please give me an idee how to use this interface to access title, artist, and so on and the callbacks specified in bt_rc.h.

Thank you for support.